# load second part of form after first part complete ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, forms

I have two forms that work as two pages, however I want to compile them into one page.

The first form creates a unique ID (**sheet_ID**) and then the next form references that **sheet_ID**.
How would I go about only displaying the second form on the same page once the user has completed the first part?

I would assume AJAX, any pointers? or links? I'm currently watching the new bostons videos on youtube on ajax.

Comment: I made the changes to this question making it very clear what I am asking, can unhold it? as the other users understood my initial question. It should be much clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do.

```
//1. first ajax request 
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "htt://yourwebsite.com",
  success:function(result){
   //2. when data will arrive this method is executed with data in result argument.

   //do what ever with data.

   //3. make other ajax request.
      $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
              url: "htt://yourwebsite.com",
          success:function(result2){

               //4. final response.. will arrive here in result2
                }
            });

  }
});
```

More on Jquery AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go, and see where I can get it too.

Answer (score 0):

i like to use jqueryUI so i use `jquery.load()`; [info](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

i asume that you have a div for the second form like:

```
<div id="secondform"></div>
```

create a submit function on the first form that contains an ajax call,

```
$("#secondform").load("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] } );
```

this call will do the db work and return the second form or a error msg

Comment: Great, I will have a look at this. Thanks